# Assembly 8086 - Finding instruction results

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, memory-segmentation

The table contains parts of memory:

[image]

The registers have these contents:

```
DS: 0726
CS: 0624
SS: 0727
ES: 0626
AX: 0003
BX: 0042
BP: 0036
SP: 002B
```

What is the result after these instructions:

```
a) mov ax, 10011b     ;ax = ____h 
b) mov ah, 4[BX]     ;ah = ____h 
c) mul bl     ;ax = ____h 
d) pop cx     ;cx =____ h 
e) mov ax, [BP]    ;ax = ________h
```

Keep in mind, the instructions are separate/sandboxed from each other. One instruction doesn't influence the next one

For context, this is not homework. I'm prepping for exams and I don't know how to solve this. I've just begun studying the 8086.

My results:

```
a) ax = 0013h
b) ah = 03h (Probably not, since I'm not sure what the 4 is doing in 4[BX]. Multiplication?)
c) ax = 00C6h 
d) cx = ? (I know how to get the address of the top of the stack, it's 729Bh, but I assume the value is in the table above? I don't know how to find it)
e) ax = F6 (Tried to make some sense of the table above. Probably not correct)
```

Comment: Why did you tag this emu8086 if you're including 386 instructions like `mov eax, [BP]`?  I assume you're still supposed to assume that this is all done in 16-bit real mode (where segment base address = segment register << 4), not protected mode or unreal mode where the segment register value is just a selector (index into the GDT).

Comment: The question gives you memory contents in seg:off format for segment = `0726h`, probably easiest to just adjust the offset by 16 to see what memory a segment base of `0727h` would "see".

Comment: `4[BX]` is alternate syntax for `[BX + 4]`.  The syntax is like C `array[idx]` syntax, i.e. `*(array + idx)`.  `eax` is a 32-bit register, 4 bytes, and there aren't a lot of zeros in the memory contents table at `726:0046`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try what you suggested. I didn't know that is a 386 instruction, I assume it's a mistake from the author of this problem.

Comment: EAX is a 32-bit register; it doesn't exist in 8086.

Comment: I assume it's a typo. I guess treat is as AX. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `BP` or `SP` is used in addressing, the default segment register is `SS`, otherwise it's `DS`.
Rewrite the first column of memory dump table with linear address, i.e. instead of seg:offs calculate 16*seg+offs. This gives addresses

```
07260
07270
07280
07290
072A0
```

Ad **d)**: `pop cx` loads a word from `SS:SP`, which is 0727:002B, which corresponds to linear address 0729B. At B-th column of fourth line we can see 00 12, so the answer is **cx = 1200h**.

Ad **e)**: `mov ax,[BP]` loads a word from `SS:BP`, which is 0727:0036, which corresponds with linear address 072A6. At 6-th position in the last line we can see 18 24, so the answer is **ax = 2418h**.